# libGDX imagebutton seeing double

Tags: libgdx, gui

If I leave my imagebuttons' width and height alone I get larger buttons than I'd like:

```
    radio.setX(wu*35);
    radio.setY(hu*20);
```

[image]

When I replace/add to the lines above with setbounds or setWidth/setHeight functions, I get this:

```
    radio.setBounds(wu * 35, hu*20, wu * 12, hu * 12);
```

[image]

It did get smaller, but now it appears to be two images.  What is going on?  I always run into this issue, across multiple screens and projects.  My attempts to resolve it include scaling the native images to be closer to the size I want them to appear in-game, and using the other button methods that deal with sizing, such as setScaleX.

Answer (score 0):

After running this problem by the libGDX forum, the prevailing wisdom is that widgets were meant to be used inside tables.  While I like the built-in functions provided by the button class, such as swapping out the images used on mouseover, mousedown, disabled, etc. events, I think I can duplicate this feature with the right listener and an Image actor.